# Convert JLabel matrix to Graphics Display

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I recently finished a project involving a JPanel containing a matrix of JLabels, each of which had their own MouseListener added to them in order to become active/inactive as the user wishes. The project worked, but I received complaints that the project was very slow on older computers, and I understand that the way I did it, while easy, was horribly inefficient. Here is a simplified version of the code that I wrote:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class LifeDriver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setSize(950, 850);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setContentPane(new LifePanel(40, 50));
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
class LifePanel extends JPanel {
   private Cell[][] grid;
   private static int nR, nC;
   public LifePanel(int row, int column) {
      nR = row;
      nC = column;
      grid = new Cell[row][column];
      setLayout(new GridLayout(row, column, 1, 1));
      for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
         for (int c = 0; c < column; c++)
         {
           grid[r][c] = new Cell();
           add(grid[r][c]);
         }
   }
}
class Cell extends JLabel
{
   private boolean alive;
   private static boolean mouseDown;
   public Cell() {
      setOpaque(true);
      addMouseListener(new Mouse());
      kill();
   }
   public void revive() {
      setAlive(true);
   }
   public void kill() {
      setAlive(false);
   }
   public void setAlive(boolean arg) {
      alive = arg;
      if (arg)
         setBackground(Color.RED);
      else
         setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   }
   private class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         mouseDown = true;
         if (alive)
            kill();
         else 
            revive();
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         mouseDown = false;
      }

      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         if (mouseDown)
            if (alive)
               kill();
            else 
               revive();
      }
   }
}
```

I want to go back and change this so that I have one MouseListener in `LifePanel`, and using `getX()` and `getY()`, determine which "Cell" has been clicked (no longer extending JLabel) and have that Cell change its color, then paint itself on the panel. Something like:

```
class LifePanel extends JPanel {
   BufferedImage myImage;
   Graphics g;
   ...
   class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         grid[someRow][someColumn].draw(g) //use e.getX() and e.getY()
      }
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         //similar to above
      }
   }
}

class Cell {
   //other methods
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(myColor);
      g.fillRect(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight);
   }
}
```

How would I determine the proper values to use in these two situations, so that mouse clicks would result in the same outcome as the original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a 2D array.

Instead you would use an `ArrayList` that contains your `Cell` objects. The `Cell` object could contain two properties:

1. a Rectangle object to represent the size/location of where the Cell should be painted
2. the Color of the Cell when it is painted.

Then the custom painting code in your panel will simply iterate through the ArrayList and paint each cell.

For the MouseListener you would get the Point of the mouse click and than again iterate through the ArrayList and use the Rectangle.contains(...) method to determine is the Cell contains the mouse point. When you find the proper Cell you do your processing.

Check out the `Draw On Component` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It shows the concept of doing the painting using this approach. You will need to add your own code for the mouse handling.

Comment: Great idea! I'll certainly take a look into this.

Comment: Oh! I figured out what was wrong. I was resizing the BufferedImage as I drew it on the panel. The reason I asked was because last time I tried, my getX() and getY() were off. I see why now. However, I do appreciate the Rectangle suggestion- I believe it will help clean up my code. Plus, it gave me a reason to say `getRect()`.